# Proving that $X^{\{1,2\}}$ is isomorphic to $X \times X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I am trying to figure out a proof for $$X^{\{1,2\}} \cong X \times X$$
given that
$$X^{\{1,2\}} =\{ f:\{1,2\} \rightarrow X\,|\, f\, \text{is a function}\}$$

I need help structuring a proof by defining a function and proving that it is bijective for $X^{\{1,2\}} \rightarrow X \times X$. Does anyone have any idea how to prove this?

Comment: Isomorphic in which sense? What structure needs to be preserved here?

Answer (score 2):

The isomorphism is given explicitly by sending the function $f\colon \{1,2\}\to X$ to the ordered pair $\bigl(f(1),f(2)\bigr)$.

Answer (score 0):

The map given by pre-kidney works. Here's the definition of the function
$$\Phi : X^{\{1, 2\}} \to X \times X$$
$$\Phi(f) = (f(1), f(2))$$
Here's how to prove it. First, show that $\Phi$ is one-to-one. In particular, we must show that, if $\Phi(f) = \Phi(g)$, then $f = g$. As $f$ and $g$ are functions on $\{1, 2\}$, this amounts to showing $f(1) = g(1)$ and $f(2) = g(2)$.

Suppose $\Phi(f) = \Phi(g)$. Then, $(f(1), f(2)) = (g(1), g(2))$. For these ordered pairs to be equal, we must have $f(1) = g(1)$ and $f(2) = g(2)$, which as noted before, means $f = g$. Therefore, $\Phi$ is one-to-one.

We must also show that $\Phi$ is onto. Given any ordered pair $(a, b) \in X \times X$, we must show that some $f : X \to \{1, 2\}$ exists such that $\Phi(f) = (a, b)$. Note that $(a, b) \in X \times X$ implies that $a$ and $b$ are in $X$, so we may define a function $f : X \to \{1, 2\}$ by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} a & \text{if } x = 1 \\ b & \text{if } x = 2.\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\Phi(f) = (f(1), f(2)) = (a, b),$$
as required. Thus, $\Phi$ is onto.

Hence, $\Phi$ is one-to-one and onto, which makes it bijective.